# Is it possible to run a loop in segments? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Since I am still fairly new to js I thought it couldn't hurt to ask more experienced coders about ways to improve my coding habits and to learn efficient basics.

So im wondering if I could run, say 2 lines of code in a loop x amount of times and then x amount of times on the rest of the block.

So instead of this:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    this.shapes[i].x -= 1;
    this.shapes[i].draw(this.ctx);
}

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    this.shapes[i].x += 1;
    this.shapes[i].draw(this.ctx);
}
```

Does something like this exist?

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

    //run this section i amount of times
    this.shapes[i].x -= 1;
    this.shapes[i].draw(this.ctx);

    //then run this i amount of times
    this.shapes[i].x += 1;
    this.shapes[i].draw(this.ctx);
}
```

Comment: You can always wrap one block in something like `if(i<5){}` if you're trying to run them a different number of times. Otherwise they both achieve the same thing (Assuming the order that they run in isn't important)

Comment: @DBS, oh right I forgot to mention that I want to run the section 1 first 10 times and then section 2 10 times. With the order being important.

Comment: If you need all iterations of section one to be complete before section 2 starts, then combining them is generally not worth the extra complexity.

Comment: @DBS I see, thanks! I thought Maheer's suggestion was pretty clever aswell.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the two loops' bodies seems to be one statement.

You can use some math to determine the index and some logical statements to determine if that value should be incremented or decremented, here is an example:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 21; i++) {
    const index = i % 11;
    this.shapes[index].x += (i > 10) ? 1 : -1;
    this.shapes[index].draw(this.ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's exactly the same code you can refactor it like this:

```
for (let delta of [-1, +1]) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    this.shapes[i].x += delta;
    this.shapes[i].draw(this.ctx);
  }
}
```

Another option is to use a function using delta as a parameter

```
changeShapeByDelta = (delta) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    this.shapes[i].x += delta;
    this.shapes[i].draw(this.ctx);
  }
}
changeShapeByDelta(-1);
changeShapeByDelta(+1);
```

Another option is to deep copy your initial shapes and restore it after the first draw.

Answer (score 0):

You could ofc. define more variables then `i`:

```
for (let i = 0, j=0; i <= 10; i++, j+= 2) {

    console.log(i, j);
}
```

Or use another var in the parent scope:

```
let j = 0;
for (let i = 0, j=0; i <= 10; i++, j+= 2) {
    j += 2
    console.log(i, j);
}
```

Or just use plain old if,else and break statements. Code does not have to look nice all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop 20 times instead of 10 times and then run first code if `i<10` else run second. Below is example with simple logging.

```js
for(let i = 0;i<22;i++){
  if(i<11) console.log('first')
  else console.log('second')
}
```

Comment: OP's loops use `i <= 10` which means that if you're going to use a single loop, you'll need one with `22` iterations.

Comment: While this does combine the loops, it doesn't actually save you any computational time, nor make the code easier to read. So I think you'd be better just leaving the loops separate.

Comment: @DBS Interesting, how about Titus's answer, would that be faster/slower how would you go about testing that?

Comment: @FrankPettersson The difference in speed is going to be negligible.

Comment: @FrankPettersson You can use tools like http://jsben.ch/ to compare different snippets, though generally in small loops like this the differences are so small they will have no effect.